# Java Regex tuning

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone help where I am doing wrong?

**My sample text :**

```
{[|Name:A|Class:1|Sex:Male|][|Name:B|Class:2|Sex:Female|][|Name:C|Class:3|Sex:Male|]}
```

**Expected output:**

```
|Name:A|Class:1|Sex:Male|
Name:A
Class:1
Sex:Male
|Name:B|Class:2|Sex:Female|
Name:B
Class:2
Sex:Female
|Name:C|Class:3|Sex:Male|
Name:C
Class:3
Sex:Male
```

**Current output :**

```
|Name:A|Class:1|Sex:Male|
Name:A
Sex:Male
|Name:B|Class:2|Sex:Female|
Name:B
Sex:Female
|Name:C|Class:3|Sex:Male|
Name:C
Sex:Male
```

My program:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String example = "{[|Name:A|Class:1|Sex:Male|][|Name:B|Class:2|Sex:Female|][|Name:C|Class:3|Sex:Male|]}";

        Pattern curlyBraces = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");

        Matcher m = curlyBraces.matcher(example);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group(1));
            String element = m.group(1);
            Pattern pipe = Pattern.compile("\\|(.*?)\\|");
            Matcher mPipe = pipe.matcher(element);
            while (mPipe.find()) {
                System.out.println(mPipe.group(1));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Given that you program prints using `println`, it's extremely unlikely that your output is a single line of text, like you showed, so please format *entire* question correctly, so we know that you *want* and what you're actually *getting* right now.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `"\\|(.*?)\\|"` will only match `|Name:A|` and `|Sex:Male|` in the line

```
|Name:A|Class:1|Sex:Male|
```

because the regex consumes the characters it's matching, and the `|` between `Name:A` and `Class:1` therefore can only be matched once.

Use [lookaround assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to get around that - they don't consume the text they match:

```
        Pattern pipe = Pattern.compile("(?<=\\|).*?(?=\\|)");
        Matcher mPipe = pipe.matcher(element);
        while (mPipe.find()) {
            System.out.println(mPipe.group(0));
        }
```

Another possibility, if you're not expecting empty values, would be to match all "non-pipes" characters:

```
        Pattern pipe = Pattern.compile("[^|]+");
        Matcher mPipe = pipe.matcher(element);
        while (mPipe.find()) {
            System.out.println(mPipe.group(0));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Tim Pietzcker already discribed, the `|` gets conumed by the regex and then it can't find the `Class:1`.

But you don't need the second regex. Instead of the regex you could use a normal `string.split("|")`. Should work in your case and is probably faster:

```
String element = m.group(1);
String[] splitString = element.split("\\|"); // splitString = ["Name:A", "Class:1", "Sex:Male"]
```

To avoid empty strings in `splitString` you would have to change your first regex Pattern to `"\\[\\|(.*?)\\|\\]"`.

Comment: That gives you `["", "Name:A", "Class:1", "Sex:Male"]` though - only trailing empty splits are removed by default.

Comment: You're right, though you could adjust the first Pattern to `"\\[\\|(.*?)\\|\\]"` and then you wouldn't have the issue with the empty splits. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Java's `String#split()` treats its argument as a regex, so you still have to escape the pipe.

Comment: @AlanMoore Thanks, totally forgot that. Updated the answer.